# decode base64 in kubectl jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, base64, kubectl, json-path-expression

I have a command similar to this

```sh
kubectl get secrets \
--selector='my-selector' \
-o jsonpath='{range .items[*] }{"\n"}{.metadata.labels.cluster-name}{"."}{.metadata.namespace {":"}{"5432"}{"postgres" }{":"}{.data.password}{end}'
```

which outputs a list like this (format required)

```
cluster-name.namespace:5432:postgres:YbHF....==
cluster-name.namespace:5432:postgres:YbHF....==
cluster-name.namespace:5432:postgres:YbHF....==
```

I need to decode the base64 for this file and using the [kubectl cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) as a reference which gives this example:

```
# Output decoded secrets without external tools
kubectl get secret my-secret -o go-template='{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{"### "}}{{$k}}{{"\n"}}{{$v|base64decode}}{{"\n\n"}}{{end}}'
```

I tried the following

```sh
kubectl get secrets \
--selector='my-selector' \
-o jsonpath='{range .items[*] }{"\n"}{.metadata.labels.cluster-name}{"."}{.metadata.namespace {":"}{"5432"}{"postgres" }{":"}{.data.password|base64decode}{end}'
```

The result is that everything appears apart from the password field which is now blank, for example:

```
cluster-name.namespace:5432:postgres:
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: jsonpath does not support all the same functions as go-template that's why they're separate; you'll be much happier using `-o go-template` for that task since the cheat sheet has already shown 90% of the answer

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out using the `-o go-template` as you suggested. Discovered it doesn't like square brackets or dashes but managed to fix those issues fairly quickly.

Comment: @user13898676 would mind posting an answer since you find a solution?

Comment: @thomas sure no probs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @mdaniel suggestion I used the `-o go-template`

My main syntaxal changes were removing the [ ], ie, `{range .items[*] }` to `{{range .items}}'`

And if a key contained a `-` then `{.metadata.labels.cluster-name}` became `{{index .metadata.labels "cluster-name"}}`

My solution below which enabled the base64 decode to work:

```
kubectl get secrets \
--selector='my-selector' \
-o go-template='{{range .items}}{{"\n"}}{{index .metadata.labels "cluster-name"}}{{"."}}{{.metadata.namespace }}{{":"}}{{"5432"}}{{"postgres"}}{{":"}}{{.data.password|base64decode}}{{end}}'
```